# Losing current_user with Devise and Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, devise

I am logging in user default devise views. I am overriding `after_sign_in_path` in my application controller.

This code prints my user:

```
logger.info current_user.to_json
```

After that I am returning a url, i.e. return '/sites'.
I am redirected to Redirected to http://www.mysite.com/sites, going to SitesController. If I print current_user in SitesController index action, it is nil.

What is happening?  I am behind nginx. It works well on my local env.
I really need help, I have been stucked for too much time!!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone has the same problem. I deleted the cookies and it worked! 
I dont know why.